# SKProductsRequest before screen shows

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a simple question: **How do I load the `SKProduct`s before the screen loads?**

I want to do this because they start to load in `viewWillAppear` but that isn't enough and it takes 1-3 seconds or even more depending on the internet speed for the IAPs to properly load and if the user presses any button to buy an IAP the app crashes because they haven't loaded.

So how to I make sure that they are loaded when the screen shows up?

NOTE: It's not the initial screen. It's a separate one which shows up when the user presses a button.

Comment: put some overlay with activity indicator, trying to load everything on launch screen so long will make users leave your app and never come back, user have to see that something is going on

Comment: If it's on the first screen then you can't preload. You can make a message that says "connecting to app store" while it's loading.

Comment: It's not on the main screen. There's a button in the main screen which leads to the purchases screen. Can I start loading when I press the button and pass the data along or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a complete fix for this but I disabled the buttons until the app contacts the AppStore. Not perfect because users wait a few seconds and app crashes if you press the buttons right after they are enabled but it's an improvement and I'm fine with that.